# Game Center banner wont show

Tags: iphone, game-center

In my iPhone game I have Game Center leaderboards. When the player is authenticated with game center, the "Welcome back" dialog wont show (some times it just blink, but most of the time it do not show at all). The game center integration is working, I can see the scores in the game center app and if the player is not authenticated it will ask for his credentials.

Now I am adding achievements for my game, so what was a minor issue is now a major. Since the same problem happen with the achievement unlocked banner, the player has no feedback when he unlock the achievement (I don't want to use a custom banner, I want to use game center's).

I have no clue to start looking for a solution. I did everthing like in my previous game (which game center banner works), except for using OpenGL ES 2 instead of 1.

Have anyone had this problem before? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**: Forgot to mention, achievement.showsCompletionBanner is being correctly set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:false] to disable view rotation animation. That was causing the issues with Game Center banners. After removing that line it works.